# Possibly hacked but not sure Help!

Tags: solidity, transactions, contract-invocation

I recently had most ERC20 tokens moved from a MEW wallet through the individual ERC20 contracts.  Does anyone know how this may have happened?  I am sending pertinent info from one on etherscan.io

1) overview of transaction link for just one of many

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x3ebbec532fc960ee63c0135cc300630393f7c2e399cad22f77c3a1b97f767506

2) Copy of event logs from above link for just that one of many

[3]    Address      0x80bc5512561c7f85a3a9508c7df7901b370fa1df
   Topics   [0] 0xddf252ad1be2c89b69c2b068fc378daa952ba7f163c4a11628f55a4df523b3ef
[1] 0x000000000000000000000000ae2995da17b61a605851e4f317216d68e1015c3e
[2] 0x00000000000000000000000059b8f95b66382d88500ceb238d4c4cdd4582049e
   Data 
 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000878a552480b3c6e93c

3) The Public ether address above smartcontarct move was made from

0xAe2995da17B61A605851e4F317216D68e1015c3E

4) Public address where tokens were sent to through each individual contract

0x59B8f95B66382d88500ceB238d4C4CdD4582049e

5) Could some one help me understand what happened here.  One morning, I woke up to emails indicating all of these transactions occured.  I am not a coder or anything but I was very deligent about not using Prvt key or Keystore file associated with this wallet.  Could some one have hacked me? Then wrote some type of script that would initiate sending of each individual token at a specific time? Could someone help me understand how transactions move through smart contracts.  And if I was attacked by hacker, What should I do to my computer to remove any possible future access?

I know it is alot to ask but any help would be much appreciated as I feel that if I better understand the flow I may be able to better protect in the future.

Comment: don't have time to dig too deep right now, but upon first glance, you had a `transfer` in, then a `transfer` out, meaning there was no `approve` in between that would give someone "permission" to move your tokens. the only way to do that is with the private keys. it sucks, but it sounds like someone has your pk, I'd recommend you move whatever tokens remaining to a "newly-generated" wallet until you figure things out.

Comment: Thanks...I already did.. I am wracking my brain trying to figure it out.  Not only prvt key but password that was only known by me and never written down or stored on computer.  Although it was input on a few times when I wanted import to other computers that I own.  Any info would be grateful.  Thanks , again.

Comment: The strangest thing is that they didn't take the ETH itself that was in the wallet and I was able to move that out.

Comment: fyi - there was this incident a while back https://www.reddit.com/r/CryptoCurrency/comments/7p61hx/myetherwallet_compromised_blue_team_announcing/

Comment: Thanks...looking into incident now.  I have also started a solidity learning course.  I just want to know the flow of movements to see if this was an actual hack or possibly wolf in sheep clothing, if you get my drift.